# The lower bound of bivariate normal distribution

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, measure-concentration, lower-bounds

Suppose $(Z_1, Z_2)$ is the zero-mean bivariate normal distribution with covariance $\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & \rho; \\ \rho & 1\end{matrix} \right)$ with positive $\rho > 0$. What I want to know a valuable tighy lower bound of the probability
$$\mathrm{P} \left( Z_1 > z_1, Z_2 < z_2\right)$$
where $z_1, z_2$ are some positive constants.

PS:
There are various valuable lower bound for the tail probability $\mathrm{P} \left( Z_1 > z_1, Z_2 > z_2\right)$ with positive $\rho > 0$, see p495-p499 in [Continuous Bivariate Distributions](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b101765). Can we transform $\mathrm{P} \left( Z_1 > z_1, - Z_2 > -z_2\right)$ to $\mathrm{P} \left( Z_1 > z_1, Z_2 > z_2\right)$ keeping the correlation coefficient positive?

Comment: Instead of $\rho>1$ (which can never happen), did you mean $\rho>0$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis . Yes $\rho > 0$! Thanks!

Comment: Also, "valuable tighy" should apparently be "valuable tight". Even so, what do you mean by that, specifically?

Comment: Thanks! It is a typo. “Tight” means I want the lower bound is relatively sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h:=z_1$, $k:=z_2$, and $r:=\rho\ge0$. We want to lower-bound $P(Z_1>h,Z_2<k)$. Formula (2.11) in the [paper by Willink](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/STA-200031505) (cited the book you linked) gives the following upper bound on $P(Z_1>h,Z_2>k)$:
$$P(Z_1>h,Z_2>k) \\ 
\le\Phi(-h)\Big[\Phi\Big(\frac{rh-k}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\Big)
+re^{(h^2-k^2)/2}\,\Phi\Big(\frac{rk-h}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\Big)\Big] \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for $h>0$ and states certain optimality properties of this bound; here, as usual, $\Phi$ denotes the standard normal cdf.

Since $P(Z_1>h,Z_2<k)=1-\Phi(h)-P(Z_1>h,Z_2>k)=\Phi(-h)-P(Z_1>h,Z_2>k)$, immediately from \eqref{1} we get the following lower bound on $P(Z_1>h,Z_2<k)$:
$$P(Z_1>h,Z_2<k) \\ 
\ge\Phi(-h)\Big[\Phi\Big(\frac{k-rh}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\Big)
-re^{(h^2-k^2)/2}\,\Phi\Big(\frac{rk-h}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\Big)\Big].   \tag{2}\label{2}$$
Inequality \eqref{2} will turn into the equality when $r=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the right-hand side of the inequality in equation (2) may be negative if $\Phi\left(\frac{k-r h}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right) < r e^{\left(h^2-k^2\right) / 2} \Phi\left(\frac{r k-h}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right)$. If this is the case, is there an alternative formula that we can use instead?

Comment: @香结丁 : If the lower bound in (2) on $P(Z_1>h,Z_2<k)$ is $\le0$, then of course this lower bound is trivial. But then the upper bound on $P(Z_1>h,Z_2>k)$ in (1) will be greater than the trivial upper bound $\Phi(-h)=P(Z_1>h)$ on $P(Z_1>h,Z_2>k)$. You seemed to say that the bounds like that in (1) are valuable. So, the bound in (2) is equally valuable. Clearly, one cannot get an upper bound on $P(Z_1>h,Z_2<k)$ that will be tight for all $h,k$ -- except for the tautological bound, the probability $P(Z_1>h,Z_2<k)$ itself.

Comment: I am good now! Thanks so much! I just checked this website messages.